# UITableView not refreshing

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am creating a list and displaying it in a UITableView. While viewing I want to delete an item and then save the updated list, allowing me to refresh the old list with a refresh button. I use a button to save the current list, then a refresh button to reload the data into the view.  The problem is the code within the save button always runs, even when I don't press the button. I can explain best like this:

```
btnSave.TouchUpInside += delegate { _ListCopy = new List<Tasks>();
}; 

btnReset.TouchUpInside += delegate {
tblTotal.ReloadData();
tblTotal.DataSource = new ListDataSource(_ListCopy,txtTotalCost);
};

tblTotal.DataSource = new ListDataSource (_ListOfTasks,txtTotalCost);
```

When I run this the table view shows the `_ListOfTasks`list, when I press `btnReset` the `_ListCopy` is reloaded as the data source.  The issue I am having is that the value for `_ListCopy` is assigned even when I don't press `btnSave`. In this case the view is cleared. If I comment out the line `_listCopy = new List<Tasks>();` I receive a null reference exception in the table view Data Source here:

```
public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section)
{ return _ListOfTasks.Count; }  <-- exception
```

indicating to me that the value of `_ListCopy` is empty. I thought I could make `_ListCopy = _ListOfTasks` in place of `new List`. But, for some reason the code is running in the save button regardless, so I am never able to save the correct list value when I want it.  Why is`_ListCopy` be assigned a value without telling it?  I do not assign it a value anywhere else either. Can someone explain what is happening?  Is there a different solution that I could use instead?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is happening with just what you've shown.  The first thing that jumps out at me is that you call ReloadData() before you update your datasource - I would expect it to be the other way.  Secondly, TableViews have built in capability to delete items - why are you not using that?  If you post more of your code we may be able to help more.

Comment: Deleting from the table is working.  This an estimating app. for  a painting business.  Each task is calculated and saved in a list, which can then be viewed in the table.  Sometimes a customer will want to know the cost if a task is deleted. I want to store the original estimate, then doing any changes, but have the ability to restore the original list.  I first tried to simply make a copy of the original list, and when I press the reset button the copy would be sent to the table data source, but I am not able to get it to work that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had my outlets setup wrong.  For some reason I had two outlets wired to `btnreset`  and no outlets for `btnsave`. So when I pressed reset, I was also firing off the code for `btnsave`.  I solved the whole issue by correcting my outlets.  As for making a copy of the original list: I was trying to simply make `_ListCopy = _ListOfTasks` for the save function.  This only pointed to the memory location of `_ListOfTasks`, which included any changes.  I corrected this by writing a foreach loop to copy one list to the other

```
foreach( var task in _ListOfTasks) 
{
    _ListCopy.Add(task);
}
```

Now I can press save and the first estimate is stored.  I can do any deletions, and if the customer wants to revisit the initial estimate I can refresh the data.